# Does GRANTPRIVILEGES overwrite an existing user and password?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

Does the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myblog.* TO "wordpress"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "summer";
```

If executed, set a new password, when there is already an existing user wordpress with password winter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.

> When the IDENTIFIED BY clause is present and you have global grant privileges, the password becomes the new password for the account, even if the account exists and already has a password. With no IDENTIFIED BY clause, the account password remains unchanged.

Quoted from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Answer (score 0):

> When the IDENTIFIED BY clause is present and you have global grant privileges, the password becomes the new password for the account, even if the account exists and already has a password. With no IDENTIFIED BY clause, the account password remains unchanged.

From: [MySql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)